# Symfony3 : Relation One to Many return empty object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.4

I am trying to get the content of the One to Many `author` attribute in my `Strip` entity. The relation is between the `Account` and the `Strip` entities, bidirectional, and possessed by the `Strip` entity.

Here is my code for both of them:

**Strip.php**

```
/**
* Strip
*
* @ORM\Table(name="strip")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\StripRepository")
*/
class Strip
{
//...
    /**
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Account", inversedBy="strips")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="author_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $author;
//...
}
```

**Account.php**

```
/**
 * Account
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="account")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AccountRepository")
 */
class Account
{
    //...
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Strip", mappedBy="author")
     */
    private $strips;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->strips = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    //...
}
```

When I try to get the `author` attribute from a `strip`, I get an empty `account` with the right `id`, but empty on the other fields (`username`, `slug`, ...).

For example, here is what a `dump($strip->getAuthor())` returns:

```
MyController.php on line 326:
Account {#773 ▼
  +__isInitialized__: false
  -id: 1
  -username: null
  -email: null
  -emailIsPublic: 0
  -password: null
  -avatar: null
  -biography: null
  -level: 1
  -registerDate: null
  -strips: null
  #slug: null
   …2
}
```

Here are screenshots of my database showing that this relation is correctly registered:

Database screenshot strip table:
[image: Database screenshot strip table]

Database screenshot account table:
[image: Database screenshot account table]

Comment: Pretty sure it's lazy loading. How do you get the data?

Comment: me too .... @goto can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How I solved this problem**

I did a custom joined query in `StripRepository.php` to get both of the `Account` and `Strip` entities content:

**StripRepository.php**

```
class StripRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function findAuthors($strip)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                ->createQuery(
                        'SELECT s, a 
                        FROM AppBundle:Strip s
                        JOIN s.author a
                        WHERE s.id = :id'
                )
                ->setParameter('id', $strip);

        try
        {
            return $query->getSingleResult();
        }
        catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**What was the problem ?**

Doctrine2 uses lazy loading by default and so doing that allows to load all the content from both entities, instead of just loading the content from `Strip` entity.

I read the Symfony documentation again about Doctrine associations where I found the example code I used:

> Of course, if you know up front that you'll need to access both objects, you can [...] issue a join in the original query.

[Joining Related Records - Symfony 3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/associations.html#joining-related-records)

Thanks to Mocrates who put me on the lead:

> Or Better solution make a custom query in a StripRepository and select Author

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine2 use lazy loading.

> Whenever you have a managed entity instance at hand, you can traverse and use any associations of that entity that are configured LAZY as if they were in-memory already. Doctrine will automatically load the associated objects on demand through the concept of lazy-loading

Hi it's a fetch lazy by Doctrine ... try to put  in your :

```
/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Strip", mappedBy="author", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $strips;
```

Or Better solution make a custom query in a StripRepository and select Author

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('s')
     ->addSelect('a')
     ->join('s.author', 'a')
```